# How to trigger PropertyChanged event in WPF chart

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF Chart Control successfully adds and clears Data and refreshes chart when checkbox is toggled because it includes 'UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged', however, I'm not sure how to trigger the same event in code behind from OnDataAnalyzed(string data, int channelNumber) method.

```
public partial class MainWindowChart : Window
{
    public MainWindowChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void Notify(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public void OnDataAnalyzed(string data, int channelNumber)
    {
        //Code needed to trigger PropertyChanged event that updates BarChart1.
    }
}
```

MainWindowChart.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPFControlTester.MainWindowChart"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="589" Width="1008"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:KeyhanControls.Chart;assembly=KeyhanControls"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WPFControlTester">
    <Window.Resources>
        <my:Bool2Visibility x:Key="B2V"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid> 

        //Code removed for simplicity...

        <controls:BarChart x:Name="BarChart1" LegendPropertyName="WorkType" VerticalPropertyName="Value" HorizontalPropertyName="Year" FontFamily="Tahoma"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">

        //Code removed for simplicity...

        </controls:BarChart>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10">
            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                <CheckBox Content="Can change bars visibility" IsChecked="{Binding Path=CanChangeLegendVisibility, ElementName=BarChart1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />        
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

namespace KeyhanControls.Chart

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultProperty("Legends")]
public partial class BarChart : UserControl
{
    public BarChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

   //Code removed for simplicity...

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanChangeLegendVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CanChangeLegendVisibility", typeof(bool), typeof(BarChart),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, (s, e) => { (s as BarChart).CanChangeLegendVisibility = (bool)e.NewValue; }));
    public bool CanChangeLegendVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(CanChangeLegendVisibilityProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CanChangeLegendVisibilityProperty, value);
            Notify("CanChangeLegendVisibility");
            Draw();
        }
    }

   //Code removed for simplicity...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Notify(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

   //Code removed for simplicity...

}

[System.ComponentModel.DefaultEvent("IsVisibleChanged")]
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultProperty("LegendType")]
public class Legend : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    //Code removed for simplicity...

    private bool _isVisible = true;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return _isVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (_isVisible != value)
            {
                _isVisible = value;
                Notify("IsVisible");
                if (IsVisibleChanged != null)
                    IsVisibleChanged(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler IsVisibleChanged;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void Notify(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

//Below code is closer to data and channelNumber parameter source

clsAnalysis.cs

```
 public delegate void dlgAnalysis_Analyzed(string data, int channelNumber);
 public event dlgAnalysis_Analyzed analysis_Analyzed;
```

clsCommand.cs

```
 private void Analysis_DataAnalyzed(string data, int channelNumber)//Fired from the analysis module.
{
    transmitData(channelNumber, data);
}

public void newClientSelected(clsLVI_Generic_Item item)
{
    analysisModule = new clsAnalysis(SENSOR_DELIMITER, wMain.cSettings.SensitiveAnalysisMode)
    hookAnalysisEvents();
}

private void hookAnalysisEvents()
{
    analysisModule.analysis_Analyzed += wChart.OnDataAnalyzed;
}
```

Comment: Just a sidenote - only include the code that's super relevant to your question - makes it easier to give you a quick answer. To confirm: do you want the "PropertyChanged" event to also call the OnDataAnalyzed method you have? Or do you want to add the method as a separate event handler?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Adding a method as a separate event handler is preferred. I found a workaround and I'm not sure if it (see answer) is more ideal or that which you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my below solution is ideal or not. Perhaps someone can comment on it and/or an alternative solution. Thanks

```
    public void OnDataAnalyzed(string data, int channelNumber)
    {
       // MessageBox.Show("Analyzed");
        Data.Clear();
        Data.Add(new MyData() { Year = 1, Value = Convert.ToInt32(data.Substring(7, 2)), WorkType = WorkTypes.Violet });

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(() => BarChart1.CanChangeLegendVisibility = true));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to approach this, one is to change your event handler and add it to your event like so:

```
public void OnDataAnalyzed(object sender, PropertyChangedArgs args)
{
    // whatever you do
}

PropertyChanged += OnDataAnalyzed;
```

The problem here that you're missing out on the parameters that you currently have assigned for your method may not be in PropertyChangedArgs (I can't find it's structure in your code). I'm not sure where those parameters fit in because there's so much code in both examples - if you can shorten it to only the most relevant stuff, I can give you more feedback?

Comment: Parameters are passed from a different object with a different signature as you can see. I'm not sure if that code will help, but I added it to my question.